# Having trouble filling out ImageView from database method

Tags: java, android

So I have been working on the Android platform and I have run into a problem. I have been using FireBase as my choice of database to store images uploaded from the app. When the user picks an image to upload, the picture is encoded with Base64 onto a string, and this is what is saved in the database. Now, I would like to populate an ImageView on another activity within the app with all of the pictures uploaded in the database, by decoding the string onto a bitmap. However, I am having trouble with the method that grabs the data from the db in order to populate this ImageView:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


public ImageView imageView;
public Bitmap[] imagesDecoded;
public int i = 0;
private Context mContext;
public String holdsImage = "";

//these are just methods required by the ImageAdapter
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

// create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    //more code to set up the imageView
    if (convertView == null) {
        // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(250, 250));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }




    //setting up array for images extracted from database, this is where it gets messy
    //This is the method used for the database to retrieve values from it
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://myapp.firebaseio.com/posts");
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            long flyerCount = snapshot.getChildrenCount();
            int flyerCountInt = (int) flyerCount;
            imagesDecoded = new Bitmap[flyerCountInt];
            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                Flyer post = postSnapshot.getValue(Flyer.class);
                holdsImage = post.getTitle();
                turnImageStringToImage(holdsImage);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });


    imageView.setImageBitmap(imagesDecoded[position]);
    return imageView;
}







private void turnImageStringToImage(String s){

        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(s, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        imagesDecoded[i] = decodedByte;
        i++;

}
```

So my problem is, is that whatever is happening inside of the for loop in the onDataChange method, isn't usable outside of it. For example, if I tried to use the holdsImage string after it has already been assigned the string post.getTitle() after the method onDataChange, the string would go back to having a value of "", which is what it was initialized as on a global scope outside of all these methods. Normally this would be solvable if I could place the line:

```
imageView.setImageBitmap(imagesDecoded[position]);
```

inside of the for loop to populate the ImageView there, but the position variable then gives me an error saying that it needs to be declared final, and that is not possible since it is being declared as a parameter of the getView method. I have also tried to have the contents of the turnImageStringToImage inside of the for loop, and that doesn't work either. No matter what I do, whatever happens inside of that method is not transferred onto whatever was written to so that i can use it outside of the method. What is confusing about all this is that all these variables and array are declared as global, so I am not understanding why their value reverts to what it was after the method onDataChange runs. I have also tried to create an object and modify one of its values in the loop but when i access that value outside of the method it still isn't what it was assigned in there. Is there anything I can do to essentially keep the contents of the array that were written while inside of that for loop in the onDataChange method?

Comment: "that is not possible since it is being declared as a parameter of the getView method" You can just throw a final at the parameter declaration, not sure if it will still override... anyway you need to make use of a debugger to understand whats going on.

Comment: I did, and the problem was that any variables that were set a value to inside of the onDataChange method, would lose that value after the method was done